# Wordpress: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_get_attachment_src()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a dynamic bootstrap carousel, where I want to display the blog's thumbnail and the title.

I'm using bootstrap 4 to fulfill my needs.

when I implied the code, it got me this error on my localhost

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_get_attachment_src() in C:\wamp64\www\wpress\wp-content\themes\bassfacemusics-in\index.php on line 35

here's the full line of code from where the carousel starts:

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'cat' => 1,
            'post_per_page' => 4
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if($query->have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php $i = 0; ?>
            <?php while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_src($thumb_id,true); ?>
                <div class="carousel-item <?php if($i === 0): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php $thumb_url[0] ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>">
                </div>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endwhile ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
        <a href="#slider" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#slider" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) instead of `wp_get_attachment_src()`?

Comment: I've changed the code with  wp_get_attachment_image_src(); but it doesn't displaying the image

Comment: Did you adjust the parameters you provide? Because `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` does not accept an integer and a boolean.

Comment: where can I adjust these parameters?

Comment: this is to show that the image should be treated as an icon or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is not function called `wp_get_attachment_src(int $id, bool $icon)` in Wordpress.

It seems like you want to use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) instead.

To use it you need to change the following line:

```
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_src($thumb_id,true);
```

To this:

```
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail', true);
```

The second paramter has the following doducmentation:

> (string|array) (Optional) Image size. Accepts any valid image size, or an array of width and height values in pixels (in that order).
>
> Default value: 'thumbnail'

Because you seem to want to set the third parameter, [you can **not** simply skip the second parameter](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default), but need to set it explicitly. That is why `'thumbnail'` is provided as a paremter in the call and not omitted, eventhough it is the default value.

The result will be an array with the information about an image, or `false` in case of an error.

```
array [
    0 => url
    1 => width
    2 => height
    4 => is_intermediate
]
```

An example implementation is:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id);

if ($image !== false) : ?>
    <img src="<?= $image[0] ?>" width="<?= $image[1] ?>" height="<?= $image[2] ?>" />
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: The images are showing but not around the carousel.